# the inverse of Sticky Element

Tags: css

I need to keep a div below the content, similar to "position:fixed;", but when the content exceeds the screen size, I want this div to follow the content and position itself at the end of the content.

it should be here when the content is smaller than the screen:
[image]

but using "position:fixed;", it stays here:
[image]

it should be here:
[image]

I've tried making the Sticky function work in reverse, sticking to the end of the page until it's gone, but to no avail. Is there a way to do this?

At this moment, the only solution found is to stipulate a minimum height for the  and make the new div position itself below, but I would like to know if there is a more efficient way to do it.

```css
        *{
            margin:0
        }
        #content{
            min-height: calc(100vh - 50px);
        }
        .element{
            background-color: yellow;
            min-height:50px
        }
```

```html
<body>
    
    <div id="content">
        <h1>Test</h1>
        only way I got<br>
        asdasdasd<br>
        asdasdasd<br>
    </div>
    <div class="element">
        Hellow
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: please share minimum reproducible source code?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I didn't put any code, because the only way I managed to make it work so far is using a #content{min-height: calc(100vh - 50px);}, I would like to know if there is a more efficient or correct way to do this or if this is the correct way

Comment: Well, try to nest footer inside body. and give body minimum height of 100vh. and then position absolute to footer and set bottom property  to zero. In this way it will stay at bottom of screen if the content is less than screen and will start moving downward as the content length increases

Comment: But awarre that adding position absolute will remove the footer from normal flow. And at some point the content will hide behind footer or the footer will hide behind content. 
To prevent this using padding or margin in content so the content will always give room to footer

Comment: ok, I'll try this way, because the way I'm trying, an error was occurring when the device was rotated to landscape mode. thank you for the tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to achieve this.

If you know the exact height of the bottom div then you can set the minimum height of the content to be the height of the window minus the height of the bottom div. For example, if you know that the bottom div will always be `50px` in height then the content would have `min-height: calc(100vh - 50px)` (assuming that `body` has a margin of 0). This is similar to how you already seem to be doing it.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.content {
  min-height: calc(100vh - 50px);
}
.element {
  height: 50px;
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur vel lacus ut ligula auctor feugiat vehicula vitae justo.</p>
</div>
<div class="element">
  Text
</div>
```

If the bottom div has an unknown height then you'll need to make use of a wrapping element, and use flex to space them out. The wrapping element will need a minimum height of the screen height, and it will need to use flex to display its children in a column, spacing them at the top and bottom. In the example we can use `body` as the wrapping element.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: stretch;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.element {
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur vel lacus ut ligula auctor feugiat vehicula vitae justo.</p>
</div>
<div class="element">
  Text
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you a lot!!this is what i was looking for, i couldn't believe it didn't exist